# File Sharing between local computer and Virtual machine on azure

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, fileshare

I am working on creating a file share between local system and Virtual machine on Azure. I am a newbie in this area! Any pointers to achieve this will be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Azure File Share can mount to multiple places and all the places share the same File Share, it means they share all the things in the File Share. If you expect this, just go ahead to create the File Share and mount it to your local system and the virtual machine. Follow the steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-linux).

Comment: Thank you for the response.. I want to achieve the task outlined in [this article](http://haishibai.blogspot.com/2013/05/walkthrough-file-sharing-between-your.html) but I dont see the option to create Gateway as mentioned in step 7. Are the option/settings different now? OR I can follow the same steps as mentioned in your response?

Comment: @KSMB It is the subnet of the VNet and it aims to create a subnet name GatewaySubnet, it's the P2S VPN, take a look at the steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-point-to-site-resource-manager-portal).

Comment: I have created the Virtual Network Gateway and stuck at Certificate generation. Can I create self signed root certificate?

Comment: @KSMB Of course, you can. The next document from what I provide shows it.

Comment: As I am testing this feature/service , I am concerned about the associated cost. Any pointers that I should be aware of?

Comment: @KSMB In my opinion, the VPN is an expensive service. If you do not mind going through the Internet. I recommend you use the File Share directly without a VPN. But if you focus on security, the VPN is a secure way.